# Getting file after curl HTTP POST form

Tags: curl

I am trying to complete a form on a website then get a text after I complete the form

I am currently running the following command:

`curl -d "name=x&password=y" http://www.h.com//a.php`

Problem is I am getting as output the a.php file and cannot seem to get how I can get the text file that I should get after completing the form.
Thanks.

Comment: There is simply not enough information here to provide an answer. What is the actual URL you're POSTing to? Have you tried that from the command line? Are you actually receiving the a.php file as a *download* or are you receiving the *output* of that file as text?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly the issue is that the PHP related apache configuration is not configured on the host where apache is running. or even that PHP is not installed.

Comment: This is the [command line version of curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), unrelated to php.

Comment: yes I knew it, but if a PHP page gets downloaded without getting interpreted in to html then it means that there is some problem in webserver configuration or PHP is not installed.